# Using bigram using Stanford NLP in java

Tags: token, stanford-nlp, tokenize, n-gram

I am using Stanford NLP API for document collection and this is the code i used for tokenization

```
              PTBTokenizer<CoreLabel> ptbt = new PTBTokenizer<>(reader,
                                  new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
                                while (ptbt.hasNext()) {
                            CoreLabel token = ptbt.next();
                            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
                           }
```

this code however delimited on white space. I mean it convert words like ALARM Activated in to two words ALARM and Activated. I guess bigram  could solve the problem but i am not sure how to use it here. Can Any body suggest some thing to use bigram with PTBtokenizer or how to use bigram in tokenization using Stanford NLP.